# ChemoSpec can't find getManyCsv function

Tags: r, spectrum, infrared, chemistry

I'm trying to create the Spectra object (.RData), just like suggested on ChemoSpec.pdf (see the code below), and I get an error message like this:

"could not find getManyCsv function"

How can I fix it? Any suggestion is appreciated. I have R version 3.1.0 and ChemoSpec version 2.0-2.

Here is the code:

```
getManyCsv(gr.crit = c("ICLPS", "PEPS"), gr.cols = c("red3", "dodgerblue4"),freq.unit = "ppm", int.unit = "peak intensity", descrip = "PS Study",out.file = "PS")
```

Cheers,

Awel

Comment: Please show that actual code that you ran.

Comment: @eipi10 - code added. I hope it can be fixed. I've been searching the www, but I still haven't found anything that helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found on:

```
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ChemoSpec/NEWS
```

following:

```
##### Version 2.0.0
Date: 2013-12-07
>> normSpectra modified to avoid integer overflow.
>> Modified plotScree & plotScree2 so that data sets with less than 10 components plot.
>> Freshened up the README.md file.
>> To facilitate using expressions in plot titles, argument 'title' has been removed from all         functions that use base or lattice graphics and now one should use 'main'. The 'title' argument    remains for the rgl graphics functions.  THIS WILL BREAK EARLIER CODE, hence the move to a new major version.
>> Semantic versioning is now in effect.  See semver.org for details.
>> getManyCsv has been removed (deprecated for one year now).  Use files2SpectraObject instead.
```

So it might be necessary to use files2SpectraObject instead of getManyCsv.